# creating new variable multiple ifelse statements with a large dataframe

Tags: r

***SAMPLE DATA*** (just one row)

```
CNTRCT_NBR   year CF_ANNUAL_1   CF_ANNUAL_2 CF_ANNUAL_3 CF_ANNUAL_4 CF_ANNUAL_5 CF_ANNUAL_6 CF_ANNUAL_7 CF_ANNUAL_8 CF_ANNUAL_9 CF_ANNUAL_10    CF_ANNUAL_11    CF_ANNUAL_12    CF_ANNUAL_13    CF_ANNUAL_14    CF_ANNUAL_15    CF_ANNUAL_16    CF_ANNUAL_17    CF_ANNUAL_18    CF_ANNUAL_19    CF_ANNUAL_20    CF_ANNUAL_21    CF_ANNUAL_22    CF_ANNUAL_23    CF_ANNUAL_24    CF_ANNUAL_25    CF_ANNUAL_26    CF_ANNUAL_27    CF_ANNUAL_28    CF_ANNUAL_29    CF_ANNUAL_30
00222L 2 351.1 175.55   175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55  175.55
```

I am working with a very large dataframe (400,000+ rows), and am trying to create a new variable that is based on conditions. This new variable will equal a already existing column value, depending on what the year value is.

```
aux304$CF_FINAL <- NA
within(aux304, aux304$CF_FINAL <- ifelse(aux304$year == 1, aux304     $CF_ANNUAL_1, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 2, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_2,
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 3, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_3,
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 4, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_4,
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 5, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_5, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 6, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_6, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 7, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_7, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 8, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_8, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 9, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_9, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 10, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_10, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 11, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_11, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 12, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_12, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 13, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_13, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 14, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_14, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 15, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_15, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 16, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_16, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 17, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_17, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 18, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_18, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 19, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_19, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 20, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_20, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 21, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_21, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 22, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_22, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 23, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_23, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 24, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_24, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 25, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_25, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 26, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_26, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 27, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_27, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 28, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_28, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 29, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_29, 
                                  ifelse(aux304$year == 30, aux304$CF_ANNUAL_30, 0)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

aux30 <- subset(aux304, select=c("CNTRCT_NBR", "year", "CF_FINAL" ))
```

I run into an error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, CF_FINAL, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 441300
```

Then, when I try to subset that database, it tells me the variable I created (`CF_FINAL`) does not exist. I assume I am running into a problem with my nested `ifelse` statements since there are a lot, so it is not creating the variable properly.

Comment: Please provide some sample data so we can replicate the issue

Comment: I would look into `mutate` and `case_when` from dplyr

Comment: Is it `Year` like in the one row example or `year` like in the code?

Comment: it is year, I will edit that in the sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
# generate example data
year <- 1:30
mat  <- diag(101:130)
df   <- as.data.frame(cbind(year, mat))
colnames(df) <- c("year", paste0("annual",1:30))

# solution
df$final <- NA
for(i in 1:30) {
    df[df$year==i, "final"] <- df[df$year==i, paste0("annual",i)]
}
```

Comment: I am trying to add the value in that column though, not just the name.

Comment: I don't understand.  My code creates a column called `final` and then puts the value of (for example) `annual20` into `final` for just those rows where `year==20`

Comment: would I be able to do this without changing the names of my columns? or would I have to change the column names to be able to work with the paste0("annual, 1:30)?

Comment: Because you number your columns sequentially, there is no need to rename.  Just use `paste0("CF_ANNUAL_", i)`.

Comment: If my answer (or any other answer) solved your problem, please mark the answer as "accepted".  This is good practice so that answerers get rewarded for their efforts and so that other folks with the same question (who wind up on this page) can more-easily find a working answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like @AndS. suggested, you can use `mutate` and `case_when`.

```
library(tidyverse)

aux304 <- aux304 %>% # a pipe moves to next command
     mutate( #to create a new variable
       CF_FINAL = 
        case_when( #runs a series of ifelse statements
           year == 1 ~ CF_ANNUAL_1, #framework: if ~ then
           year == 2 ~ CF_ANNUAL_2,
           ...,
           TRUE ~ 0
     )
   )
```

Since there is a clear pattern here, you might look into `map`, but if this is only happening once or you want to brute force it, `case_when` provides a cleaner option that helps reduce code errors.

Good luck!